# Move file from s3 to EMR and un-tar it (Scala)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a large `.tar.gz` file stored on S3, and I want to transfer it to EMR HDFS or a temporary S3 bucket and then decompress it. This will allow me to access and read smaller files within the archive.

Currently, my approach involves using a shell script to download the file from S3 to the local machine using the AWS CLI. After downloading, I run a Scala/Spark job on the uncompressed file to generate the desired results.

However, I would like to combine these steps into a single Scala/Spark job. This job should handle moving the file from S3 to EMR (or another temporary S3 location), uncompressing it, and processing the individual files.

I'm aware of [S3DistCp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html), which can transfer files between S3 and EMR. But I'm unsure how to integrate it into my Scala code. Currently, I can only execute `S3DistCp` within the EMR shell. Is there a library available for working with this command in Scala?

Additionally, when using `S3DistCp` with the `--outputCodec=None` option, it only decompresses the **gzipped** portion of the file. What steps should I take to handle the **tar** part of the archive?

Comment: I got into some problem, what was your final solution then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the S3DistCp directly from EMR.
One approach would be to SSH to the master node and execute the command in a terminal window.

If you prefer to create a cluster that has some data on HDFS, you can submit one or more steps directly in the AWS Management Console when creating a cluster. In the console add step dialog box, fill the fields in the a similar way:

```
Step type: Custom JAR
Name*: S3DistCp Step
JAR location: command-runner.jar
Arguments: s3-dist-cp --src s3://<your-bucket-name>/ --dest /data/input/<where-you-want-your-input> --outputCodec=None --targetSize 10
Action of failure: Continue
```

In your case, I would add another step that will unzip the gzipped file, when creating the cluster (you can do that in the EMR web console).
Read more in the AWS EMR docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-work-with-steps.html

Finally, you can run on your unzipped files.

Cheers!

Comment: I want to do it with Scala, what you said need to be done in EMR console